# Run loop inside shell to run java

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, while-loop

I have basic knowledge of shell script. here, I have json file (Basepath.json) with multiple values on it. In my shell script, I parse a values from json and run awk cmd to remove first & last character of one value, convert it into variable and now run (java -jar ApiMakr.jar $ControllerPath) to create one API Proxy

how to make this keep looping so that java takes another value from json (with awk condition applied) and create multiple API proxies based on values defined in json file

Basepath.json

```
"{'_mobile_v1_accountInvestments': {}, '_resetcache_actsrcasset': {}, '_resetcache_actsummary': {}, '_resetcache_dcvision': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolio': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolio_accountdetails': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolio_enrolleeaccountdetails': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolio_planattributes': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolio_userkeys': {}, '_resetcache_userportfolioconstants': {}, '_v1_account_balance': {}, '_v1_account_performance': {}, '_v1_account_summary': {}, '_v1_account_summaryBal': {}, '_v1_account_summaryMsgInd': {}, '_v1_account_summarySocNorm': {}, '_v1_account_summaryTradeRes': {}, '_v1_actDtls': {}, '_v1_dcvisioninfo': {}, '_v1_sso_account_balance': {}, '_v1_userKeys': {}, '_v1_userportfolio': {}, '_web_v1_accountInvestments': {}}"
```

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ControllerPath=$(awk '{print substr($0, 4, length($1)-5)}' basepath.json)

echo $ControllerPath

#echo $(pwd)
java -jar ApiMakr.jar $(pwd) Retirement_userportfolio$ControllerPath userportfolio INDV_GET retirement_userportfolio_$ControllerPath userportfolio
```

for removing first and last character using awk:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 4, length($1)-5)}' basepath.json
mobile_v1_accountInvestments
```

Comment: `tr -d '"' < basepath.json  | tr "'" '"' | jq -r '. | keys[]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your input file isn't really json.  You need to massage it a bit to make it valid, and then you can just loop over the keys.  Something  like:

```
tr -d '"' < basepath.json | tr "'" '"' | jq -r '. | keys[]' | while read ControllerPath; do

java -jar ...

done
```

The first two `tr`'s are just deleting the double quotes from the input and then replacing all the single quotes with double quotes.  Then use `jq` to parse the json.

Comment: This is fantastic! This actually worked and resolve my issue. Thanks a ton! You have a lovely weekend sir